# Stop debugging one project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I regularly debug several projects contained in *one* solution using the same Visual Studio instance. For that, I use the "Debug"->"Start new instance" menu on each project I want to debug:

[image: Screenshot]

When using the menu "Debug"->"Stop debugging", all projects debug sessions are stopped.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I stop the debug session of one project only?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Did you try killing the specific process through task manager?

Comment: @rocky: I was looking for a less "brutal" solution, but it seems to be working fine with the Task Manager.

Comment: I got that :) but I don't think there is one :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bring up the Processes window (normally found under Debug -> Windows -> Processes), right click on the process you wish to stop debugging and slect either "Detach Process" (to stop debugging and leave the process running) or "Terminate Process"  (to terminate the process)

[image: Screenshot of the Processes window in Visual Studio]

(This screenshot is of Visual Studio 2012, however the dialog is very similar in previous versions of Visual Studio)